# In Shiny/R when I click on image link (actionLink) the app crashes

Tags: r, shiny

I have this app here:

Here is the code for the module:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

years <- 2015:2022

list_actions <- list(
  letters[1:3],
  letters[4:6],
  letters[7:9],
  letters[10:12],
  letters[13:15],
  letters[16:18],
  letters[19:21],
  letters[22:24]
)

list_actions <- list_actions %>% set_names(years)


module_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    uiOutput(ns('letter_1'))

  )
}

module_server <- function(id, app_control_input) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$letter_1 <- renderUI({
        h1(app_control_input())
      })

    }
  )
}
```

This is the app's main code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioGroupButtons(
    inputId = 'seasons',
    direction = 'horizontal',
    justified = 'TRUE',
    size = 'sm',
    label = '',

    choices = sort(years,decreasing = TRUE),
    selected = '2022'
  ),

  htmlOutput('actions_icons'),

  module_UI('overview')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$actions_icons <- renderUI({

    list_actions[[input$seasons]]  %>%
      map(~ actionLink(label = .x,
        inputId = paste0(.x)))

        })


  letter <- reactive({list_actions[[input$seasons]][1]})

  letters %>% map( ~ observeEvent(input[[paste0(.x)]], {
    letter(.x)
  }))

  module_server('overview', app_control_input = letter)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I click over the years the letter that are showed to me are correctly. So, if I click on `2015` the letters showed are  `a b c`

My problem is: when I click on the letters the app crashes.

For example when I run the app `2022` is already selected. So the letters `v w x`are displayed, and the letter `w` is already choose.  **But when I click on `x` the app crashes**.

**How can I avoid this?**

Also, is very important that every time I select (click) the year, the first letter is selected/displayed bellow, and then I will be able to choose others letters as well.

Any help guys?

Comment: what is the error message in your Rsession or in the shiny-server log?

Comment: @Vida thanks for your time: `Warning: Error in letter: unused argument (.x)`is the message error.

Comment: This error happens when I click on the letters that are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my <- reactiveValues()
  output$actions_icons <- renderUI({
    
    list_actions[[input$seasons]]  %>%
      map(~ actionLink(label = .x,
                       inputId = paste0(.x)))
    
  })
  
  observe({
    my$letter <- list_actions[[input$seasons]][1]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$seasons, {
    my_list <- list_actions[[input$seasons]]
    n <- length(list_actions[[input$seasons]])
    lapply(1:n, function(i){
      observeEvent(input[[my_list[i]]], {
        my$letter <- list_actions[[input$seasons]][i]
        print(my$letter)
      })
    })
  })
  
  module_server('overview', app_control_input = reactive(my$letter))
  
}
```